# Unable to use anaconda jupyter on non default startup folder in cygwin

Tags: anaconda, cygwin, jupyter

I am successfully able to use jupyter that is part of anaconda 3.7 distribution by double clicking on the 
windows short cut which runs

```
C:\cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3 C:\Cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"
```

With an invocation such as above, I am able to only use notebooks from directory hierarchy

```
C:\Users\%USER%
```

To be able to use notebooks from any arbitrary folder, I made up this bash function to be used from a cygwin shell

```
APYTHON=/usr/local/anaconda3/python
CONDA_DIR=/usr/local/anaconda3

function sjupyter {
    DIR=$1

    if [ -z "$DIR" ]; then
        echo "sjupyter <dir-name>"
        return 1
    fi


    $APYTHON `cygpath -wp $CONDA_DIR/cwp.py` `cygpath -wp $CONDA_DIR` \
        `cygpath -wp $APYTHON` \
        `cygpath -wp $CONDA_DIR/Scripts/jupyter-notebook-script.py` \
        `cygpath -wp $PWD`
}
```

When I invoke jupyter using above function
$ jupyter .
I get a url such as

```
http://localhost:8889/?token=9591ce5364b5d92c938aef193f7c6a28d28801eff3153534
```

which when I paste in the browser allows me to open notebooks in current working directory hierarchy.
However, when I try to execute this statement

```
import pandas as pd
```

in a notebook from the browser, it hangs with a * next to In prompt

```
In[*]
```

and see this messages in bash console

```
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling startup files:
[W 12:33:29.038 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 097cfd44
-a0fa-4da2-b2e4-47dc6641ffce
```

Tried restarting kernel from the browser and it did not help.

What is the right way to run anaconda jupyter to use notebooks from non default working directory in a cygwin environment?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing cwp.py, running jupyter command with --notebook-dir arguments able to
run access notebooks from any directory

```
APYTHON=/usr/local/anaconda3/python
CONDA_DIR=/usr/local/anaconda3

sjupyter ()
{
    DIR=$1;
    if [ -z "$DIR" ]; then
        DIR=.;
    fi;
    if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
        echo "dir-name $DIR does not exist";
        echo "sjupyter <dir-name>";
        return 1;
    fi;
    PATH=$CONDA_DIR/Library/bin:$PATH jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=`cygpath -wp $DIR`
}
```